# how to get row id which just added

Tags: c#, sql-server

My c# button adding some data in one table. how can i get id of this row? does anybody have idea?

```
  private static void InsertIntoTransportation(string ZednadebNumber, DateTime DateTime, int SellerID, int BuyerID, string TransStart, string TransEnd, decimal Quantity, string LoadType, string LoadName, int DriverID, decimal Cost, decimal FuelUsed, decimal salary)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Transportation (DriverID, ClientIDAsSeller, ClientIDAsBuyer, ZednadebNumber, LoadName, TransStart, TransEnd, LoadType, Quantity, Cost, FuelUsed, DateTime) VALUES (@DriverID, @ClientIDAsSeller, @ClientIDAsBuyer, @ZednadebNumber, @LoadName, @TransStart, @TransEnd, @LoadType, @Quantity, @Cost, @FuelUsed, @DateTime)", new SqlConnection(Program.ConnectionString)))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DriverID", DriverID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientIDAsSeller", SellerID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientIDAsBuyer", BuyerID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZednadebNumber", ZednadebNumber);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoadName", LoadName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransStart", TransStart);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TransEnd", TransEnd);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoadType", LoadType);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", Quantity);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cost", Cost);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FuelUsed", FuelUsed);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTime", DateTime);
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Salary (DriverID, TransportationID, Salary) VALUES (@DID, @@IDENTITY, @Salary)", new SqlConnection(Program.ConnectionString));
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DID", DriverID);
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Salary", salary);
                cmd1.Connection.Open();
                cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd1.Connection.Close();
                cmd.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("ვერ ვახერხებ მონაცემთა ბაზასთან კავშირს, დაწრმუნდით თქვენი კომპიუტერის ინტერნეტთან კავშირის გამართულობაში.", "შეცდომა !!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code please? We need to see your code to see how you adding data? Adding line by line, or adding list? What is the type of your ID column (int,uniqueidentifier,nvarchar)? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My c# button adding some data in one
>   table. how can i get id of this row?
>   does anybody have idea?

Your code example provided inserts two rows.

Either way, simply alter the statement to included "; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()" at the end, and get a scalar result from the command.

Assuming your row ID is a standard integer field (rather than a bigint)

```
// Edit your command text to have "; SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()" at the end. 
int? insertedId = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as int?;
if (insertedId.HasValue) 
 { 
    //  success! 
 }
```

Note that if your row isn't using auto incrementing integer/big-int, then this won't work.

In addition, I would strongly suggest that you consider moving your statements to stored procedures, if this is for anything other than test/sample code.

Separating your SQL code out of your C# means that you can re-use common statements (think of them as Methods). Alternatively, consider using an ORM solution.

Answer (score 1):

On an MS SQL Server, My preference is for the [output clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx). You wouldn't be executing a non-query, it would be a reader (even though it's technically an insert) - the resultset from your insert will then contain one row with the field(s) you choose. This is useful if you have a ROWVERSION (TIMESTAMP) column that you also need for updates that might follow (prevents you from doing another read).

Edit - Just use OUTPUT, not OUTPUT INTO (which is more useful for SQL Server side code than C#).

This works well with sprocs and triggers too, as opposed to scope_identity (which, when using instead-of triggers is in a different scope and so returns null), or @@identity and all of it's issues.

Answer (score -1):

Some of my co-worker developers will perfrom a query after the insert to return the identity value.  As a DBA there are other ways to get it as indicated by Alexander.  While the query will produce extra IO on the network at least it should still be in cache and not cause any more Disk IO.

Comment: Performing a query to find out the value inserted will lead to race conditions if two or more of these processes are operating concurrently.  Instead, use the provided SCOPE_IDENTITY functionality to return the generated ID in one atomic operation. See my answer for an example.

Comment: Will, I guess I should have just entered this into a comment as I was tryint to agree with Alexander and not suggest the dual query.